# get the category name from one table where id = c_Id in other table

Tags: php, database, blogs

I am trying to code a simple blog to get experience with php.
The blog has not only posts but also categories a post can belong to. (post with the title "lorem ipsum" has category 1 which is horror for e.g.)
there are two more table but for this they're unnecessary.

```
table: posts                      table: categories
id = 1*                           category = Fantasy
c_Id = 2**                        id = 2*
title = hello world
subheading = greeting the world
content = hello.
```

When I click on the category "Fantasy" on my blog it should get me all the posts 
 with the category I've clicked on.
 I have a selfmade framework with a CategoryRepository in which I interact with the 
 database and a PostsController that has functions to render the sites on my blog.

When I click on a category it leads me to this url("horror" represents the different categories):

http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror

I have this function in my PostsController in which I am trying to get the category-name out of the url(I didn't manage to get it with a session/POST even though I need the category-name dynamic and I strictly want the category-name and *not* the category-id in the url.)

```
public function categoryOverview() {
  $url = 'http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror';
  $endOfUrl = basename($url);

  if($endOfUrl == "Horror") {
    $categoryName = "Horror";
  } 

  $categories = $this->categoryRepository->allCategories();

  $idFromCategory = $this->categoryRepository->idFromCategory($categoryName); 

  $this->render("cats/categoryOverview", [
    'id' => $idFromCategory,
  'categories' => $categories,
  ]);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I managed to get the end of the url dynamically(probably an ugly code but it worked at least):

```
public function categoryOverview() {
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
  $categoryName = basename($url);

  $categories = $this->categoryRepository->allCategories(); 

  $idFromCategory = $this->categoryRepository- 
  >getPostFromCategory($categoryName); 

  $this->render("cats/categoryOverview", [
    'id' => $idFromCategory,
    'categories' => $categories,
  ]);
}
```

**UDAPTE END**

And this is the idFromCategory() in the CategoryRepository which should get the id and the category from the category that's in the url aka the on I clicked on:

```
public function idFromCategory($categoryName) {
  $table = $this->getTableName();
  $model = $this->getModelName();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE category = :category");
  $stmt->execute(['category' => $categoryName]);

  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
  $idFromCategory = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

  var_dump($idFromCategory);

  return $idFromCategory;
 }
```

1. Could I do it with a Session? The categories to click on are in the header in the navbar, I go through the categories in the table with a foreach to put them in the menu, this works excellent. But when I put the $_SESSION['categoryID'] = $category->category; I would alwasy get the last categories's ID.
2. There must be a more easy way than what I am trying to do, but how?
3. I don't really now why, but I just can't seem to get all the posts of one category to be listed when I click on the category, even though it sounds so easy.

I hope anyone understands what I'm writing here :D
I am really just at the beginning of programming with php so I really hope that someone can help me with this; even if it's just saying that my code is horrible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a join for get all the post related  to a category

```
   SELECT posts.*, categories.* FROM posts 
   INNER JOIN categories ON posts.c_id = categories.id
   WHERE categories.category = :category
```

Comment: object(App\Category\CategoryModel)#23 (6) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["category"]=> NULL ["c_Id"]=> int(1) ["title"]=> string(5) "hallo" ["subheading"]=> string(49) "... ist der erste Beitrag der Kategorie "Horror"." ["content"]=> string(19) "asfasf asdfghjkl" }

Comment: This is the outcome; is it bad that"category" is NULL? actually it shouldn't?

Comment: nope it`s not.                      
    $url='http://localhost:8888/blog/public/index.php/categories/Horror';
    $endOfUrl = basename($url);

    if($endOfUrl == "Horror") {
      $categoryName = "Horror";
    }   This is where it gets the $categoryName, right now it only works with Horror, another thing I would like to change but don't know how

Comment: it did this, that's why I said that it's not null. This is the output when I var_dump it : string(6) "Horror"

Comment: I think the problem is that with "SELECT post.* FROM posts" we don't get the 'category' since this isn't in the posts-table... how do I get it then? Another query?